# How to handle the automation in selenium for the dropdown with check

Tags: selenium, select, checkbox

In my project I need to test the web app with selenium automation for the dropdown with multiselect checkbox. where I have the dropdown and i have to check the checkboxes inside that dropdown using the selenium code .

Tried code of selenium to select dropdown's checkboxes using xpath.

```
Select dropdown1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("contract_ids")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/button")).Selected;
elementToClick.click();
```

or by tag name

```
 Select dropdown1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("contract_ids")));
    WebElement checkBoxElement1=driver.findElement(By.tagName("checkBox"));
    checkBoxElement1.click();
```

[image: Image of dropdown with the checkbox]

Comment: And the result of this test was...?  Clearly it is not working but, what is the error/issue you are seeing?

Comment: showing an error  (Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException)

Answer (score 1):

[This site](https://www.igniteui.com/combo/selection-and-checkboxes) have same dropdown as you have mentioned this code might help you:

```
driver.get("https://www.igniteui.com/combo/selection-and-checkboxes");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='checkboxSelectCombo']/div/div[1]/div")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li/div[contains(.,'ASP.NET Controls')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[contains(.,'ASP.NET Controls')]")).click();
```

Use `Explicit Wait` until your element get visible and then perform click to select checkboxes